# Have D3 force directed graph form a specific shape?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a D3 force graph form a specific shape. Here's what I mean. This what the graph looks like right now.

[image]

What I want is to be able to have the nodes form a shape such as this:

[image]
(ultra pro ms paint skills)

So I want all the nodes to be inside the black line, forming this shape. Is there a way to do this inside d3?

Comment: To select all the nodes inside the free hand drawing area you can use point in polygon (http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/5575904) in d3.js. Then you will need to write your logic to create path to form a shape from node attributes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this directly with the D3 force layout. It doesn't allow for any additional constraints. What you can do is enforce this layout yourself in the `tick` handler function:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  // iterate over all nodes, check if they're in a position they shouldn't be in
  // if so, adjust the position
});
```

That said, you almost certainly don't need the force layout in this case. As suggested in the comments, it would be easier to manually position the nodes along the shape that you want. Again, there's no support in D3 to do that.